# How to read only alphabetical characters from a txt file while ignoring white spaces and other special characters?

Tags: c, character, whitespace, space

I use pointers to open a `.txt` file that consists of several paragraphs. I used a for loop to store the `.txt` file into a `char word[i]` array and then `printf` it.

Everything worked well except I don't want to store white spaces and special characters. I only want to store alphabetical characters such as ABCD......Z into my `char word[i]` array.

I know I have to put `if` functions into my for loops, but I don't know the exact syntax. Please help.

here is the for loop of my code :

```
 for (i=0; i<1730; i++ )
   {
       fscanf(fptr,"%c", &word[i]);
       printf("%c", word[i]);
   };
```

Comment: You can easily look up how to use `if` in a C textbook or on the net.

Comment: `if` isn't function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char chr;
    char *file_name="IdentifiedParts.txt";
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "r");
    while ( (fscanf(fptr,"%c",&chr)) != EOF ) {
           //ASCII values : 65-90 => A-Z ,  97-122 => a-z
        if( (chr >= 97 && chr <= 122 ) || (chr >= 65 && chr <= 90 ) ) {
             printf("%c", chr);
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}

      OR 

   while ( (fscanf(fptr,"%c",&chr)) != EOF ) {
          if(isalpha(chr)) {
            printf("%c", chr);
          }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `char chr;;`. `fgets` returns an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: `chr >= 97 && 122 <= chr` meant `122 <= chr`

Comment: Hi BLUEPIXY , 
 U know C langauge ,First u compile this code after u put the comment.
(chr >= 97 && 122 <= chr )  it means 97, 98 ,99 .........122 (a,b,c........z)
(chr >= 65 && 90 <= chr )  it means  65, 66 ,67 .........90 (A,B,C........Z)
 Both condition matching only sort list tha alphabetical characters.

Comment: Are you seriously saying it? LOL. You do not compile and run, right? see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/37GvxF)

Comment: Your code is wrong plz change the if condition 
if(chr >= 97 && 122 <= chr ) to if(chr >= 97 && chr <= 122) 
Demo link :[DEMO](http://ideone.com/af7C5z)

Answer (score -1):

something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char word[1730];
    FILE* fptr = fopen("input.c", "r");
    int i, ch;

    for (i = 0; i<1730 && (ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF; i++ ){
        if(isalpha(ch))
            printf("%c", word[i]=ch);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char word[1730];
    FILE* fptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(fptr)){
        while(1 == fscanf(fptr, "%1729[A-Za-z]", word)){
            printf("%s", word);
        }
        fscanf(fptr, "%*[^A-Za-z]");
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi BlUEPIXY, thank you for your answer. Your code does show all the characters without the white spaces and special characters. But unfortunately the char word[i] value of each character does not seem to match with the words in the sentence: "CSthesciencethat..."                                                                                                                           For example: I tried to print out char word[0] and expect to see C as the first letter or char word[1] as S, but those are not the cases.

Comment: @UncleZhangHeorZhangHimHer try `printf("%s", word);` --> `printf("%s\n", word);`